# RuntimeError: expected a non-empty list of Tensors

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I am trying to develop a gesture recognition system using Pytorch deep learning frame work. I get this error.

```
data = torch.cat(imgs,dim=1)
RuntimeError: expected a non-empty list of Tensors
```

Comment: What's `imgs`? Share code to explain your question. [`cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.cat) operation requires a sequence of tensors.

Comment: @harshit_k Thanks. This got resolved but now I am facing this issue.
`ValueError: num_samples should be a positive integeral value, but got num_samples=0`